# How to refresh tiles icons from Windows 10 start menu?

Tags: windows-10, start-menu

The usual deletion of iconcache.db together with the content of that db (thumbnails) does not work.

The icons of the shortcuts are visible and correct, but their tile appearance is wrong. When I remove a tile from start and put it back, the wrong icon is still there.

I do not know how to correct that.

[image]

Comment: There are more cache-files to delete - try this [link](https://www.tenforums.com/tutorials/5645-rebuild-icon-cache-windows-10-a.html#option2).

Answer (score 0):

I reduced the size of a tile, the icon was correct, and then resized back to normal size, the icon was corrected.

There might another trick to force the refresh of the cache, if any.